# Why did the Community user delete a question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user

It's regarding [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194033/vba-macros-for-card-drawing-and-revealing-game)

It does not fit under any guidelines listed by [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

I agree it's a poor question but IMO it could be solved.

Any ideas why the Community user *decided* to delete it?

Comment: @hims056 I agree I haven't come across it before so thanks all clear now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user account was deleted and the post had a negative score.

From the [deletion FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> 5. The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.

Comment: That makes sense. So the user account was deleted by the owner, correct?

Comment: The account was deleted; that's all we know.

Comment: Oh, perfect, thanks for this very useful link to deletion FAQ I haven't come across it yet